# How to stop an Loading function on button click?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-ajax

I have a problem, I have to stop one Loading class on button click. I already checked some forums related to this. But didn't find an exact solution.

For example:

```
Public Sub LoadDropDown()
   Dim it As Integer
   For it = 0 To 1000000
      DropDownList1.Items.Add(it)
   Next
End Sub
```

I have to load the DropDown on Load button click and I have to cancel that on cancel button click.

Comment: Thanks @Waqas for formatting OP's code example

Comment: @Rajsmethode: I hope you are not considering seriously to build so many DropDownList Items?! You know that this also must be sent to the Client and rendered from the browser?

Comment: Yes I know that, I am just given one example as drop down list, I have the similer issue, the user want to cancel loading a gridview. i have done ajax update panel with javascript abortPostBack() methode. but it will stop the postback and the server side code will be working up to the event completing. Can you give me any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

Since populating the control happens on the server, I can't imagine way to interrupt your method from the client. The whole control is being populated, rendered, and only then sent to the client. You might interrupt the callback using ajax, but then the control wouldn't be returned at all.

An alternative could be to load the contents in chunks with ajax and append them to the control on the client-side.

Comment: I just given one example, If loading a grid view with heavy data then how user cancel that? I tried for ajax update panel, its working good, it will stop loading but the server side function will be working in background, how i can stop that?

Comment: You can't just stop server-side processing once it's running. Unfortunately that's the asynchronous nature of the web. Or at least you'd have to write a whole lot of infrastructure to mimic state so much that a 'Cancel'-Request can be mapped to a specific process that's still running somewhere in the background.

Comment: yes, Its required. Some loading functions user should have an option to cancel, otherwise he have to wait upto completing the loading even if he dont want. thats the reason I am trying any possiblities for stop the process. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

There is no formal way to do what you're asking, but you should be able to achieve the same result if you refactor your code. If certain content shouldn't be loaded for certain users, do that logic in your code behind before it renders to the page.

Answer (score 0):

Per your response to the other answers...

You could consider doing multiple my_ddl.items.add() calls on a timer.  Would involve multiple, separate postbacks / ajax calls.  For example:

```
1) add records for 2 seconds (instead of a fixed number of records at a time)
2) check for session("continue") = "true"
3) add more records for 2 more seconds
4) check session("continue")
...
```

At some point, user clicks cancel, which assigns "false" to session("continue").  Next time your loop checks session("continue"), it will see that it's false and exit.

This would give you a partially-loaded data control.  You might want other code to wipe-out the partial update.

Comment: But how I can change the session continue to false? If I write the codding in cancel button event it should get fired only after finishing load button even, for that wat I can do? How I can change session value from client side?

Comment: Well I think it's possible through the script manager and web methods, but you don't have to use session -- can be anything that holds a value on your page.  For example, you could use javascript  for your cancel button to cause it to set a value in your dom (like a hidden field's text value, etc.)

Comment: I tried your methode its working, But still i have problem, if I using Stored procedure or sql query, I think that we cant stop like this, In that case what I can do? please advice me

Answer (score 0):

I think you could accomplish this with a Session Variable.  Forgive me, but I'll have to provide the example in C#, but I'm sure you can get the general idea of this.

```
   private bool CancelRequested
        {
            get
            {
                if (Session["CancelRequested"] == null)
                    return false;
                else
                    return (bool)Session["CancelRequested"];
            }
            set
            {
                Session["CancelRequested"] = value;
            }
        }

        public void LoadDropDown()
        {
            for (int it = 0; it <= 1000000; it++)
            {
                if (CancelRequested)
                {
                    CancelRequested = false;
                    break;
                }                    
                //Your logic here
            }
        }

        protected void btnCancelRequest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CancelRequested = true;
        }
```

The idea here is that the inital loop checks a Session variable to see if it should continue or break out of the loop.  If you have a button on the page that will allow the user to set this Session variable to "true", they can essential communicate to the inital request and cause it to break out of the loop.  I'm not sure if this would fully accomplish what you're looking to achieve, but hopefully it helps.